# Wrapping a 3rd party class / data type with SWIG

Tags: java, c++, opencv, swig

My problem is that I have a C++ class here with a 3rd party library (openCV) included. I need to handle it and work with this class in java application and I came up with SWIG to wrap all together to use it with in my java code.

It works quite fine but I have an issue when it gets to a function in which I need a cv::Mat (Matrix data type in openCV) as input parameter. Have a look at the following...

This is my c++ header information:

```
class bridge
{
  public:
      cv::Mat IfindReciept(cv::Mat);
}
```

My SWIG interface file looks like this to define a typemap for the cv::Mat data type:

```
%typemap(jstype) cv::Mat "org.opencv.core.Mat"
%typemap(jtype) cv::Mat "long"
%typemap(jni) cv::Mat "jlong"

%typemap(in) cv::Mat {
    $1 = cv::Mat($input);
}
```

When I generate the wrapper via SWIG I get a file called SWIGTYPE_p_cv__Mat.java which defines the data type like this:

```
public class SWIGTYPE_p_cv__Mat {
  private long swigCPtr;

  protected SWIGTYPE_p_cv__Mat(long cPtr, boolean futureUse) {
    swigCPtr = cPtr;
  }

  protected SWIGTYPE_p_cv__Mat() {
    swigCPtr = 0;
  }

  protected static long getCPtr(SWIGTYPE_p_cv__Mat obj) {
    return (obj == null) ? 0 : obj.swigCPtr;
  }
}
```

According to the SWIG documentation this is done when SWIG is not able to recognize the type.

What am I doing wrong? Maybe I've overseen something because I worked the whole night on this.

[Mevatron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16125811/referencing-specific-classes-in-an-external-library-with-swig) didn't work for me.

Hope some one can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Hi to build a cv::Mat wrapper to java i did the following:

```
%typemap(jstype) cv::Mat "org.opencv.core.Mat" // the C/C++ type cv::Mat corresponds to the JAVA type org.opencv.core.Mat (jstype: C++ type corresponds to JAVA type)
%typemap(javain) cv::Mat "$javainput.getNativeObjAddr()" // javain tells SWIG how to pass the JAVA object to the intermediary JNI class (e.g. swig_exampleJNI.java); see next step also
%typemap(jtype) cv::Mat "long" // the C/C++ type cv::Mat corresponds to the JAVA intermediary type long. JAVA intermediary types are used in the intermediary JNI class (e.g. swig_exampleJNI.java)
// the typemap for in specifies how to create the C/C++ object out of the datatype specified in jni
// this is C/C++ code which is injected in the C/C++ JNI function to create the cv::Mat for further processing in the C/C++ code
%typemap(in) cv::Mat {
    $1 = **(cv::Mat **)&$input;
}
%typemap(javaout) cv::Mat {
    return new org.opencv.core.Mat($jnicall);
}
```

You can see the description on each line. This will allow you to pass and return a Mat object in java.